# Sentence construction using "was"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is the below sentence is correct?

> "This home loan which I was paying is closed now. ***It was closed*** on 31st Aug 2015. I am no more paying EMIs for it now."

In above sentence *"It was closed on 31st Aug 2015"* is correct to use?

Does it have two meanings?

> a) It was closed on 31st Aug 2015 (Status)
>   b) It was closed by me on 31st Aug 2015 (Passive Voice)

Please Help.

Comment: I'd write: I was paying is ***paid off***...

Answer (score 1):

**It was closed on 31st Aug 2015** by itself is fine. It indicates **past** and the verb is used correctly. ***But in your paragraph***, it seems *verbose*.

I would suggest an addition of "Hence," before your next sentence, remove the last **now**, and rework the first part of your paragraph:

> "This home loan which I was paying until recently was closed on
>   31st Aug 2015. Hence, I am no longer paying EMIs for it."